# AWS SES sendEmail(...).promise().then(...) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-ses

using node v14.18.1

`sesLib` is an import.`const sesLib = new AWS.SESV2({ ...})` is defined elsewhere

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) documentation:

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments:
> callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

I am using the SendEmail feature in AWS SES V2 SDK using with `.promise()` method to test for empty/null values in the **To** email address field

original code

```
const sendEmailImpl = (other_params, sesLib) => {
...
const params = { ... };
return sesLib.sendEmail(params).promise();
};
```

I tried the following code, all different variations but they result in the message -  Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
const sendEmailImpl = (other_params, sesLib) => {
...
const params = { ... };
return sesLib.sendEmail(params).promise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      resolve(data); // tried with & without resolve statement
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', JSON.stringify(err));
    reject(
      'error', JSON.stringify(err); // tried with & without reject statement
    );
    throw new Exception(...);
  });
};
```

```
const sendEmailImpl = async (other_params, sesLib) => {
...
  const params = { ... };
  var sendEmailPromise = await sesLib.sendEmail(params).promise();
  sendEmailPromise.then((ok) => {
    return ok;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', JSON.stringify(err));
    reject(
      'error', JSON.stringify(err); // tried with & without reject statement
    );
    throw new Exception(...);
  });
};
```

After running npm test and `jest`, it always returns the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
...
sesLib.sendEmail(params).promise()
^
.then((data) => {
...
```

AWS Doc about promises
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/
SES SendEmail API
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-concepts-email-format.html

Comment: `resolve` and `reject` are only used when you create your own promise using the `Promise()` constructor. They're parameters passed to your executor function, they're not global statements. When you already have a promise and are using its `then()` method, you simply return a value or another promise inside the callback.

Comment: In your second example you're awaiting the promise() call, so `sendEmailPromise` isn't the promise, it's the resolved value. If the promise doesn't return anything sendEmailPromise will be `undefined`, and if you invoke `then()` on undefined you'll get the error you describe.